# How to check if Highcharts y-axis exists

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart and I am adding dynamically y-axes.

I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/wvaGt/) and it is working perfectly.

However if you go the the example, hit "Add axis and series" multiple times, you will end up having multiple axis and series.

But in my case, if I have added an y-axis I would like to check if an y-axis with the same Id already exist and if it does, do not add the axis a second time.

Below is the copy of the example (which I did not wrote)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart',{


    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature'
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: '#F33'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        color: '#F33'   
    }]
});

// the button handlera
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
$('#add').click(function() {
    // if not exist chart.axis['rainfall-axis'] :
    chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
        id: 'rainfall-axis',
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall'
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: '#08F',
        opposite: true
    });
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        color: '#08F',
        yAxis: 'rainfall-axis',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Use !!chart.get( id )

Comment: From the documentation: [Chart.get()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in api ( [Chart.get](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.get) ) to check if an element with the given id exists.

```
var id = 'rainfall-axis';

if ( !chart.get( id ) ) {
  chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
    id: id,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall'
    },
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColor: '#08F',
    opposite: true
  });
}
else {
   alert( 'chart has an axis with id ' + id );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4f15cof/2/